# Asp.net identity caching for azure ad

Tags: asp.net, azure-active-directory, asp.net-identity

The issue that currently we are facing is our users in China have delay in signing into Azure Ad.
I want to create an Asp.net application that acts as an identity service provider for other applications.
I want my users to login to my application using their Microsoft live accounts and my application should be able to cache the identities to avoid delay.
Is it possible to implement such a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to repro in my Lab and successfully tested that my user can login without any delay of time below are the steps:

Deployed my ASP. NET application to Azure> Go to APP service> Authentication >ADD identity Provider
[image]

In the identity provider>select Microsoft account >By Default App registration will be created /Or we can create new one. >Support account type Select your account type to login users  select Any azure AD directory & [Microsoft accounts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-authentication-provider-microsoft).

[image]

After added successfully you can check or edit the identity provider.
[image]

And then tested my app which required Microsoft live accounts to sign-in users .
[image]

For further information please refer below links :

.[To Enable multi-factor authentication in Azure Active Directory B2C](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/azure/active-directory-b2c/multi-factor-authentication?pivots=b2c-user-flow).

. [Considerations for using caching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/best-practices/caching#considerations-for-using-caching).